# SUM() Several dateperiods in same dataset

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I need some ideas on how to solve a problem I have with a report query.
3 columns are in use, all in the same table, “EventDate”, “Distance” and “EventName”.
For every event registered the time and date for the event is recorded together with the “EventName”.
What I need the query to do is calculate the SUM(Distance) between what is called main events, the main events have set names but can reoccur several times a day.

I cant figure a way to write a query that uses the “EventDate” where “EventName” = ‘something’ then keeping going until you reach “EventName” = ‘Something else’ then give SUM(Distance) then start over again from the next “EventName”=’something’ and keeps doing it until there are no more records in the dataset with the “EventName”=’something’.

Sorry if this is confusing, any assistance or code snippet to get me going forward with this problem is highly appreciated.

```
    EventName              EventDate                Distance
    All Clear              2018-09-06 01:54:00.000  0
    Passing 3 Nmz          2018-09-06 02:35:00.000  0
    Commence Sea Passage   2018-09-06 03:00:00.000  10
    Commence Sea Passage   2018-09-06 03:00:00.000  0
    DailyReport            2018-09-06 12:00:00.000  119
    End Of Sea Passage     2018-09-07 05:45:00.000  335
    Pilot Embarked         2018-09-07 06:00:00.000  0
    Tug Fast               2018-09-07 07:40:00.000  0
    Mooring Commenced      2018-09-07 08:15:00.000  0
    All Fast               2018-09-07 08:45:00.000  19
    Pilot Embarked         2018-09-07 23:18:00.000  0
    Unmooring Commenced    2018-09-07 23:45:00.000  0
    All Clear              2018-09-08 00:00:00.000  0,01
    Pilot Disembarked      2018-09-08 01:30:00.000  0
    Commence Sea Passage   2018-09-08 01:40:00.000  17
    Voyage Complete        2018-09-08 01:40:00.000  0
    Voyage Commenced       2018-09-08 01:45:00.000  0
    End Of Sea Passage     2018-09-08 10:00:00.000  83
    Anchored               2018-09-08 11:00:00.000  3,2
    DailyReport            2018-09-08 12:00:00.000  0
    All Fast               2018-09-09 20:00:00.000  40
```

On the above data set i would like to have the distance from "All Clear" including "All Fast".

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and the expected result you want to have from the query?

Comment: thanks, added some sample data to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a gaps-and-islands problem.

You can generate a rank based on the type of event.
Then group on that rank and calculate the total distance from that.

**Example snippet:**

```
-- Using a table variable for testing purposes
declare @Table table (EventDate datetime, EventName varchar(30), Distance decimal(9,2));

-- Sample data
insert into @Table (EventName, EventDate, Distance) values
 ('All Clear','2018-09-06 01:54',0)
,('Passing 3 Nmz','2018-09-06 02:35',0)
,('Commence Sea Passage','2018-09-06 03:00',10)
,('Commence Sea Passage','2018-09-06 03:00',0)
,('DailyReport','2018-09-06 12:00',119)
,('End Of Sea Passage','2018-09-07 05:45',335)
,('Pilot Embarked','2018-09-07 06:00',0)
,('Tug Fast','2018-09-07 07:40',0)
,('Mooring Commenced','2018-09-07 08:15',0)
,('All Fast','2018-09-07 08:45',19)
,('Pilot Embarked','2018-09-07 23:18',0)
,('Unmooring Commenced','2018-09-07 23:45',0)
,('All Clear','2018-09-08 00:00',0.01)
,('Pilot Disembarked','2018-09-08 01:30',0)
,('Commence Sea Passage','2018-09-08 01:40',17)
,('Voyage Complete','2018-09-08 01:40',0)
,('Voyage Commenced','2018-09-08 01:45',0)
,('End Of Sea Passage','2018-09-08 10:00',83)
,('Anchored','2018-09-08 11:00',3.2)
,('DailyReport','2018-09-08 12:00',0)
,('All Fast','2018-09-09 20:00',40)
;

-- Query
;with CTE as
(
  select EventDate, Distance, EventName
   , iif(EventName = 'All Clear',1,0) as isMainEvent
  from @Table
)
select 
 min(EventDate) as MinDateTime,
 max(EventDate) as MaxDateTime,
 sum(Distance) as TotalDistance
from
(
    select *
    , row_number() over (order by EventDate) - row_number() over (partition by isMainEvent order by EventDate) as rnk
    from CTE
) q
where isMainEvent = 0
group by rnk
order by rnk;
```

**Output:**

```
MinDateTime         MaxDateTime         TotalDistance
------------------- ------------------- -------------
2018-09-06 02:35:00 2018-09-07 23:45:00        483.00
2018-09-08 01:30:00 2018-09-09 20:00:00        143.20
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the help. I’m now getting the sum for all events except the isMainEvent.
I see from your example that you manage to include the isMaintEvent also in your sum, how did you do that?

Comment: @Tommel  If you look at the first query in the CTE, the IIF just uses a simple rule for that.  And if you modify the SQL by not grouping in the outer query and just do a `select *` then you'll see how that calculated `rnk` marks the groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution. It create temporary table with only main events and then check in loop for input data sum of distances between main events:

```
/*Input Table: EventLog (EventName nvarchar(max), EventDate datetime, Distance decimal(18,2))*/
DECLARE @BeginDate AS datetime
DECLARE @EndDate AS datetime
DECLARE @RowNo AS integer
--result table
DECLARE @MainEventTable table
    (RowNumber integer,
    MainEventName nvarchar(256),
    MainEventDate datetime,
    SumDistance decimal(18,2))

--Create List of Main Events
INSERT INTO @MainEventTable (RowNumber, MainEventName, MainEventDate)
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EventDate ASC), EventName, EventDate
    FROM EventLog --!! put here name of your table
    WHERE EventName IN ('Main1','Main2','Main3') --!! put here names of main events

--check number of main events
SET @RowNo = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RowNumber),0) FROM @MainEventTable)
SET @BeginDate = CONVERT(datetime, '9999.12.12', 102)

WHILE @RowNo > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @EndDate = @BeginDate
        SET @BeginDate = (SELECT MainEventDate FROM @MainEventTable WHERE RowNumber = @RowNo)

        UPDATE @MainEventTable 
        SET SumDistance = (
            SELECT
                SUM(Distance)
            FROM EventLog --!! put here name of your table
            WHERE EventDate >= @BeginDate AND EventDate < @EndDate)
        WHERE RowNumber = @RowNo

        SET @RowNo = @RowNo - 1
    END

SELECT * FROM @MainEventTable ORDER BY RowNumber
```

Input (EventLog):

```
EventName   EventDate               Distance
NotMain     1905-07-04 00:00:00.000 2
Main3       1905-07-05 00:00:00.000 2
Main2       1905-07-06 00:00:00.000 2
NotMain     1905-07-07 00:00:00.000 3
NotMain     1905-07-08 00:00:00.000 2
Main1       1905-07-09 00:00:00.000 1
```

Output:

```
RowNumber   MainEventName   MainEventDate           SumDistance
1           Main3           1905-07-05 00:00:00.000 2
2           Main2           1905-07-06 00:00:00.000 7
3           Main1           1905-07-09 00:00:00.000 1
```